# Sitecore Database comparison

Tags: sitecore

In the control panel of sitecore 6.2 installation, the database compare option is missing.

Do we need to do any configuration in order to get that option?

I can see that option in sitecore 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find this in 6.2. "Compare databases" command is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party tool like [Razl](http://www.razl.net/). 
But this is not free.